# Update session table in database when user closes browser tab or the browser itself

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, session

I have created custom tables for user authentication and session management.

UserSession : UserSessionId pk guid, UserId fk Guid, IsActiveSession bool, IsExpired bool, AccessToken, CreatedTS, UpdatedTS, ExpiryTS

User : UserId PK Guid, Email, Country, State, City, Address,CellPhoneNo, LastLoginTS, CreatedTS, UpdatedTS,IsLockedOut

UserLogin :UserLoginId pk BIGINT, UserId FK Guid, PasswordHash, PasswordSalt, CreatedTS, UpdatedTS

I want to update the flag IsActiveSession to false in UserSession table on sql server db when user closes a tab or the browser . I know we can use beforeUnload of body in js and make an ajax call but i need a reliable code. Is there any way to handle this sort of stuff in Global.asax  ?

I am not going to use Session["Key"] stuff at all, as i am aiming for a distributed environment.

I am still designing the backend. Yet to start work on front end.

Comment: Only real options are to either expire sessions quickly and have a polling ajax request happening during a request to keep the session alive while the user is on the page, or to have an unload handler that sends a synchronous ajax request to the server, causing the server to expire the session if a new request doesn't happen shortly thereafter causing it to not expire. the short expire with keep-alive polling is easier, but less efficient than the second option. Or you could just do away with the polling and have a short expiration.

Comment: Thanks Kevin ! Can u just put a sample code or link to a code here. I did search for it but couldn't find anything satisfactory. It would be of great help.

Comment: i'm not familiar enough with asp to give a code example.

Comment: Ok No Problem. Anything on JS or jquery which could be supported by all browsers ?

Comment: Since the session database is server-side, the jquery involved wouldn't be much more than an ajax request, or an unload event handler, neither of which will come anywhere close to solving your problem without the asp to support it.